# About the sharepoint LogToHistoryListActivity.Duration

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

Does anybody know what the LogToHistoryListActivity.Duration does? I see some people set it to zero and some people keep the default negative value. I didn't find any useful information on MSDN.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure about it, but [this tutorial](http://www.psspug.org/SharePoint%20Conference%202008/Hands%20On%20Labs/Creating%20and%20Deploying%20Visual%20Studio%20Workflows%20for%20Microsoft%20Office%20SharePoint%20Server%202007%20-%20HOL315.doc) states an interesting fact:

> As we want to allow our list
>   administrator to view the history of
>   this workflow, we will now add a
>   LogToHistoryListActivity. This will
>   keep a record of the completion of the
>   task.
>
> As we will see later, SharePoint
>   **allows you to generate duration
>   reports** for workflows. Here, the
>   duration of the workflow is calculated
>   by subtracting the start time from the
>   time of task completion.

and then

> Additionally, we can open up the
>   Activity Duration workflow in Excel.
>   The data collected here was made
>   possible by the
>   LogToHistoryListActivity we created
>   earlier.